# Can I replace Lard with Ghee in tortillas?

Tags: substitutions, fat, mexican-cuisine, tortilla

I am trying to make home made tortillas and I was wondering if I can substitute Lard with Ghee as I am not too keen about the taste of lard. My understanding is that ghee, like lard doesn't have lot of moisture and hence it can be used. But I hope I can get a better answer from more experienced cooks.

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/82766/why-use-lard-in-tortilla-dough?rq=1

Comment: I am actually trying to make Tortillas with Ghee in the coming days. So I will let folks know.

Answer (score 2):

**You could try substituting leaf lard for regular lard.**

Lard has characteristics that make it perfect for tortillas.  But the big square bricks of MANTECA sometimes taste piggy even to me.

Leaf lard is super premium lard from a particular part of the pig.  I have found it only at farmers markets and occasionally at specialty butchers but of course you could order on line.  It is expensive.  It is essentially tasteless.  I bought a tub and my daughter used the entire thing for pie crust, which my lardophobic wife ate merrily.

Comment: Thanks! I am in Italy and I do not speak Italian. So I have to figure out what it is called.

Comment: For clarity, it may be better to say "substituting regular lard with leaf lard" rather than using "for." It seems to me that using "for" in that context could be interpreted in either direction, which muddles the answer unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I use coconut oil in my dough as a substitute for lard. My friend makes his with no fat at all.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/73180)

Comment: @StephenEure The OP doesn't appear to be *solely* interested in ghee as a substitution. They just don't want lard.